# Predicting credit card default

Tags: python, finance, machine-learning

I have this code for predicting credit card default and it works perfectly, but I am checking here to see if anybody could make it more efficient or compact. It is pretty long though, but please bear with me.

```
# Import necessary libraries.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Extracting data from .csv file.
file = 'C:\\Users\\alhut\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\credit card default project\\creditcard_default.csv'
dataset = pd.read_csv(file, index_col='ID')

dataset.rename(columns=lambda x: x.lower(), inplace=True)


# Preparing the data using dummy features (one-hot encoding). Base values are: other_education, female, not_married.
dataset['grad_school'] = (dataset['education'] == 1).astype('int')
dataset['universty'] = (dataset['education'] == 2).astype('int')
dataset['high_school'] = (dataset['education'] == 3).astype('int')
dataset.drop('education', axis=1, inplace=True) # Drops the education column because all the information is available in the features above.

dataset['male'] = (dataset['sex'] == 1).astype('int')
dataset.drop('sex', axis=1, inplace=True)

dataset['married'] = (dataset['marriage'] == 1).astype('int')
dataset.drop('marriage', axis=1, inplace=True)

# In the case of pay features, <= 0 means the payment was not delayed.
pay_features = ['pay_0','pay_2','pay_3','pay_4','pay_5','pay_6']
for p in pay_features:
    dataset.loc[dataset[p]<=0, p] = 0

dataset.rename(columns={'default_payment_next_month':'default'}, inplace=True) # Renames last column for convenience.


# Importing objects from sklearn to help with the predictions.
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix, precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.preprocessing import RobustScaler


# Scaling and fitting the x and y variables and creating the x and y test and train variables.
target_name = 'default'
X = dataset.drop('default', axis=1)
robust_scaler = RobustScaler()
X = robust_scaler.fit_transform(X)
y = dataset[target_name]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.15, random_state=123, stratify=y)


# Creating a confusion matrix.
def CMatrix(CM, labels=['pay','default']):
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=CM, index=labels, columns=labels)
    df.index.name='TRUE'
    df.columns.name='PREDICTION'
    df.loc['TOTAL'] = df.sum()
    df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
    return df



# Preparing a pandas DataFrame to analyze models (evaluation metrics).
metrics = pd.DataFrame(index=['accuracy', 'precision', 'recall'],
                        columns=['NULL','LogisticReg','ClassTree','NaiveBayes'])


#######################
# The Null Model.
y_pred_test = np.repeat(y_train.value_counts().idxmax(), y_test.size)
metrics.loc['accuracy','NULL'] = accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['precision','NULL'] = precision_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['recall','NULL'] = recall_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)

CM = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
CMatrix(CM)


# A. Logistic Regression.
# 1- Import the estimator object (model).
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

# 2- Create an instance of the estimator.
logistic_regression = LogisticRegression(n_jobs=-1, random_state=15)

# 3- Use the trainning data to train the estimator.
logistic_regression.fit(X_train, y_train)

# 4- Evaluate the model.
y_pred_test = logistic_regression.predict(X_test)
metrics.loc['accuracy','LogisticReg'] = accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['precision','LogisticReg'] = precision_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['recall','LogisticReg'] = recall_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)

# Confusion Matrix.
CM = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
CMatrix(CM)


# B. Classification Trees.
# 1- Import the estimator object (model).
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

# 2- Create an instance of the estimator.
class_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(min_samples_split=30, min_samples_leaf=10, random_state=10)

# 3- Use the trainning data to train the estimator.
class_tree.fit(X_train, y_train)

# 4- Evaluate the model.
y_pred_test = class_tree.predict(X_test)
metrics.loc['accuracy','ClassTree'] = accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['precision','ClassTree'] = precision_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['recall','ClassTree'] = recall_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)

# Confusion Matrix.
CM = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
CMatrix(CM)


# C. Naive Bayes Classifier
# 1- Import the estimator object (model).
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

# 2- Create an instance of the estimator.
NBC = GaussianNB()

# 3- Use the trainning data to train the estimator.
NBC.fit(X_train, y_train)

# 4- Evaluate the model.
y_pred_test = NBC.predict(X_test)
metrics.loc['accuracy','NaiveBayes'] = accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['precision','NaiveBayes'] = precision_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
metrics.loc['recall','NaiveBayes'] = recall_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)

# Confusion Matrix.
CM = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
CMatrix(CM)


#######################
# Comparing the models with percentages.
100*metrics


# Comparing the models with a bar graph.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
metrics.plot(kind='barh', ax=ax)
ax.grid();


# Adjusting the precision and recall values for the logistic regression model and the Naive Bayes Classifier model.
precision_nb, recall_nb, thresholds_nb = precision_recall_curve(y_true=y_test, probas_pred=NBC.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])
precision_lr, recall_lr, thresholds_lr = precision_recall_curve(y_true=y_test, probas_pred=logistic_regression.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1])


# Plotting the new values for the logistic regression model and the Naive Bayes Classifier model.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
ax.plot(precision_nb, recall_nb, label='NaiveBayes')
ax.plot(precision_lr, recall_lr, label='LogisticReg')
ax.set_xlabel('Precision')
ax.set_ylabel('Recall')
ax.set_title('Precision-Recall Curve')
ax.hlines(y=0.5, xmin=0, xmax=1, color='r')
ax.legend()
ax.grid();


# Creating a confusion matrix for modified Logistic Regression Classifier.
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
ax.plot(thresholds_lr, precision_lr[1:], label='Precision')
ax.plot(thresholds_lr, recall_lr[1:], label='Recall')
ax.set_xlabel('Classification Threshold')
ax.set_ylabel('Precision, Recall')
ax.set_title('Logistic Regression Classifier: Precision-Recall')
ax.hlines(y=0.6, xmin=0, xmax=1, color='r')
ax.legend()
ax.grid();


# Adjusting the threshold to 0.2.
y_pred_proba = logistic_regression.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]
y_pred_test = (y_pred_proba >= 0.2).astype('int')

# Confusion Matrix.
CM = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
print('Recall: ', str(100*recall_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)) + '%')
print('Precision: ', str(100*precision_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)) + '%')
CMatrix(CM)


#######################
# Defining a function to make individual predictions.
def make_ind_prediction(new_data):
    data = new_data.values.reshape(1, -1)
    data = robust_scaler.transform(data)
    prob = logistic_regression.predict_proba(data)[0][1]
    if prob >= 0.2:
        return 'Will default.'
    else:
        return 'Will pay.'


# Making individual predictions using given data.
from collections import OrderedDict
new_customer = OrderedDict([('limit_bal', 4000),('age', 50 ),('bill_amt1', 500),
                            ('bill_amt2', 35509 ),('bill_amt3', 689 ),('bill_amt4', 0 ),
                            ('bill_amt5', 0 ),('bill_amt6', 0 ), ('pay_amt1', 0 ),('pay_amt2', 35509 ),
                            ('pay_amt3', 0 ),('pay_amt4', 0 ),('pay_amt5', 0 ), ('pay_amt6', 0 ),
                            ('male', 1 ),('grad_school', 0 ),('university', 1 ), ('high_school', 0 ),
                            ('married', 1 ),('pay_0', -1 ),('pay_2', -1 ),('pay_3', -1 ),
                            ('pay_4', 0),('pay_5', -1), ('pay_6', 0)])

new_customer = pd.Series(new_customer)
make_ind_prediction(new_customer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not going to try a line-by-line analysis, but here are a couple broad suggestions:

- [Use a `__main__` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do), and keep the script locked away like that
- Use functions to compartmentalize logic, and [don't repeat yourself](https://dzone.com/articles/is-your-code-dry-or-wet). You are clearly aware that your code exists as largely independent blocks of logic (hence your big comment bars), so use functions to name those blocks, then orchestrate how those functions get run to pass data back and forth, making it clear what information is needed where, and making it easier to see what logic is duplicated and what is unique to each part of your task. Rule of thumb: if you're copy-pasting code and just changing variable names (e.g. when you're making plots, computing metrics, etc.), make it a function instead.
- Put your imports at the top of the file. It's cleaner, and also serves like a header that tells other coders "here are the kinds of things I'm going to do in this file."

So your code might look more like:

```
# All your other imports...
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

# ...

def run_classifier(classifier_type, classifier_kwargs, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, metrics):
    # 1- Import the estimator object (model).
    # 2- Create an instance of the estimator.
    classifier = classifier_type(**classifier_kwargs)

    # 3- Use the trainning data to train the estimator.
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

    # 4- Evaluate the model.
    y_pred_test = classifier.predict(X_test)
    name = classifier_type.__name__
    metrics.loc['accuracy', name] = accuracy_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
    metrics.loc['precision', name] = precision_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
    metrics.loc['recall', name] = recall_score(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)

    # Confusion Matrix.
    CM = confusion_matrix(y_pred=y_pred_test, y_true=y_test)
    CMatrix(CM)

    return classifier, CM

# ...

def main():
    # ...
    naive_bayes, nb_cm = run_classifier(NaiveBayes, {}, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    # etc.

    plot_pr_curve(naive_bayes, X_test, Y_test)
    # etc.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed up my code a bit based on what you told me, although I didn't see the need to use the main block. Mainly I created a model function and then used it to make the logistic regression, classification tree, and naive bayes models.

Comment: @DeathExploit The reason to use a "main block" (by which I mean the ``if __name__ == '__main__'`` block at the bottom) is so that you can keep code from being run if you import this file from other code. For example, if you wanted to interact with these functions or code from an interactive terminal, you don't necessarily want it to train a bunch of classifiers and pop a bunch of plot windows just to be able to use these functions in your terminal. If you don't use that block, it makes the file almost unusable as anything but a standalone script (just like not putting code in functions).